# Edit in Word in IE not opening Word

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, registry

In Internet Explorer there is a setting to edit the page that you are on in Word, in some cases (like mine) you do not have option to enable 'Edit in Word'. So in order to add it you must add a key in the registry, it finally showed up as you see below, this is not my image, so in my case i only have notepad and Word 2013.

[image: edit in word in IE]

When i now go to File -> Edit in Word and click it, nothing happens!

winword.exe does not show in task manager at all when clicking
I have reset IE settings

I am working with around 50 Pc's, mostly on windows 10 (some on 7) and office 2013-2019, in some Pc's this is working, and some it is not. I have done so many registry changes, not sure what else to do.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, turns out it was because IE was not being specifically run as admin, even though the user opening it is an admin, and clicking run as admin bring up no message to click OK or anything, it only works that way, I pushed out a reg hack via GPO to auto run IE as admin and all working good now... It's just strange how some users dont need to run as admin and some do...